# error: invalid suffix "x" on floating constant

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ESP 0.0001
#define F(x) x^3-2.5x^2-1.8x+2.356
void main()
{
  float x0,x1,x2,f1,f2,f0;
  int count=0;

  do
  {
  printf("\nEnter the value of x0: ");
  scanf("%f",&x0);
  }while(F(x0) > 0);
  do
  {
  printf("\nEnter the value of x1: ");
  scanf("%f",&x1);
  }while(F(x1) < 0);
  printf("\n__________________________________________________________\n");
  printf("\n    x0\t       x1\t x2\t   f0\t   f1\t   f2");
  printf("\n__________________________________________________________\n");
  do
  {
  f0=F(x0);
  f1=F(x1);
  x2=x0-((f0*(x1-x0))/(f1-f0));
  f2=F(x2);
  printf("\n%f %f %f %f %f %f",x0,x1,x2,f0,f1,f2);
  if(f0*f2<0)
   {
    x1=x2;
   }
   else
   {
    x0 = x2;
   }
  }while(fabs(f2)>ESP);
printf("\n__________________________________________________________\n");
printf("\n\nApp.root = %f",x2);
getch();
}
```

The program can't seem to read the `#define F(x) x^3-2.5x^2-1.8x+2.356` as function but when I use `#define F(x) 3*(x) - 1 - cos(x)` there's no error.

I tried `#define F(x) (x)^3-2.5(x)^2-1.8(x)+2.356`, no luck.

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator. Also `2.5x^2` --> `2.5*x*x`

Comment: what is ^ in your opinion?

Comment: and there*s no "implicit `*`".

Comment: ...such as `1.8x`

Comment: And, the entire expression (when corrected) should be parenthesised.

Comment: Use: `#define F(x) ((x)*(x)*(x) - 2.5*(x)*(x) - 1.8*(x) + 2.356)`. Note the use of paranthesis they are important as macros are just textual substitution.

Comment: ;) real mathematicians cannot dev ;)

Answer (score 0):

> F(x) x^3-2.5x^2-1.8x+2.356

1. ^ is not the power operator in C use pow(), powf() function (but in this case there is no need of it)
2. 2.5x has to be 2.5 * x - buy a book about C
3. do not #define functions make them "real"functions
4. Do not use double literals in float expressions

---

```
float F(float x)
{
  return x * x * x + 2.5f * x * x + 1.8f * x + 2.356f;
}
```

Comment: As much as I want to use that code I don't know where to place it. 